# Convert GIF Player Web Component into React Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, web-component, gif

I want to convert a [GIF Player Web Component](https://github.com/WillsonSmith/gif-player-component/blob/main/gif-player.js) into React Component.

I tried finding a React GIF Player library but there aren't any that are working fine.

Currently, [GIF Player Web Component](https://github.com/WillsonSmith/gif-player-component/blob/main/gif-player.js) looks promising but it's not available in React. It looks like:

```js
import { LitElement, html, css } from "lit";
import { GifReader } from "omggif";

class GifPlayer extends LitElement {
  static get styles() {
    return css`
      :host {
        display: inline-block;
      }
      canvas {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }
    `;
  }
  static get properties() {
    return {
      src: { type: String },
      alt: { type: String },
      autoplay: { type: Boolean },
      play: { type: Function },
      pause: { type: Function },
      restart: { type: Function },
      currentFrame: { type: Number },
      frames: { attribute: false, type: Array },
      playing: { attribute: false, type: Boolean },
      width: { attribute: false, type: Number },
      height: { attribute: false, type: Number },
    };
  }

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.currentFrame = 1;
    this.frames = [];
    this.step = this.step();
    this.play = this.play.bind(this);
    this.pause = this.pause.bind(this);
    this.renderFrame = this.renderFrame.bind(this);
    this.loadSource = this.loadSource.bind(this);
  }

  firstUpdated() {
    this.canvas = this.renderRoot.querySelector("canvas");
    this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
    this.loadSource(this.src).then(() => {
      if (this.autoplay) this.play();
    });
  }

  updated(changedProperties) {
    if (changedProperties.has("width")) {
      this.canvas.width = this.width;
      this.renderFrame(false);
    }
    if (changedProperties.has("height")) {
      this.canvas.height = this.height;
      this.renderFrame(false);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return html`<canvas role="img" aria-label=${this.alt}></canvas>`;
  }

  play() {
    if (this.animationFrame) cancelAnimationFrame(this.animationFrame);
    this.animationFrame = requestAnimationFrame(this.step);
    this.playing = true;
  }

  pause() {
    this.playing = false;
    if (this.animationFrame) cancelAnimationFrame(this.animationFrame);
  }

  restart() {
    this.currentFrame = 1;
    if (this.playing) {
      this.play();
    } else {
      this.pause();
      this.renderFrame(false);
    }
  }

  step() {
    let previousTimestamp;
    return (timestamp) => {
      if (!previousTimestamp) previousTimestamp = timestamp;
      const delta = timestamp - previousTimestamp;
      const delay = this.frames[this.currentFrame]?.delay;
      if (this.playing && delay && delta > delay) {
        previousTimestamp = timestamp;
        this.renderFrame();
      }
      this.animationFrame = requestAnimationFrame(this.step);
    };
  }

  renderFrame(progress = true) {
    if (!this.frames.length) return;
    if (this.currentFrame === this.frames.length - 1) {
      this.currentFrame = 0;
    }

    this.context.putImageData(this.frames[this.currentFrame].data, 0, 0);
    if (progress) {
      this.currentFrame = this.currentFrame + 1;
    }
  }

  async loadSource(url) {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const buffer = await response.arrayBuffer();
    const uInt8Array = new Uint8Array(buffer);
    const gifReader = new GifReader(uInt8Array);
    const gif = gifData(gifReader);
    const { width, height, frames } = gif;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.frames = frames;
    if (!this.alt) {
      this.alt = url;
    }
    this.renderFrame(false);
  }
}

function gifData(gif) {
  const frames = Array.from(frameDetails(gif));
  return { width: gif.width, height: gif.height, frames };
}

function* frameDetails(gifReader) {
  const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  const frameCount = gifReader.numFrames();
  let previousFrame;

  for (let i = 0; i < frameCount; i++) {
    const frameInfo = gifReader.frameInfo(i);
    const imageData = context.createImageData(
      gifReader.width,
      gifReader.height
    );
    if (i > 0 && frameInfo.disposal < 2) {
      imageData.data.set(new Uint8ClampedArray(previousFrame.data.data));
    }
    gifReader.decodeAndBlitFrameRGBA(i, imageData.data);
    previousFrame = {
      data: imageData,
      delay: gifReader.frameInfo(i).delay * 10,
    };
    yield previousFrame;
  }
}

customElements.define("gif-player", GifPlayer);
```

However, I don't know how to convert it to a React Component.

I want to convert it in TypeScript. I've managed to convert it a little bit like:

```
// inspired by https://github.com/WillsonSmith/gif-player-component/blob/main/gif-player.js

import React from 'react'
import { GifReader } from 'omggif'

export class GifPlayer extends React.Component {
    static get styles() {
        return `
            :host {
                display: inline-block;
            }
            canvas {
                display: block;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }
        `
    }

    static get properties() {
        return {
            src: { type: String },
            alt: { type: String },
            autoplay: { type: Boolean },
            play: { type: Function },
            pause: { type: Function },
            restart: { type: Function },
            currentFrame: { type: Number },
            frames: { attribute: false, type: Array },
            playing: { attribute: false, type: Boolean },
            width: { attribute: false, type: Number },
            height: { attribute: false, type: Number },
        }
    }

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.currentFrame = 1
        this.frames = []
        this.step = this.step()
        this.play = this.play.bind(this)
        this.pause = this.pause.bind(this)
        this.renderFrame = this.renderFrame.bind(this)
        this.loadSource = this.loadSource.bind(this)
    }

    firstUpdated = () => {
        this.canvas = this.renderRoot.querySelector('canvas')
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext('2d')
        this.loadSource(this.src).then(() => {
            if (this.autoplay) this.play()
        })
    }

    updated = (changedProperties) => {
        if (changedProperties.has('width')) {
            this.canvas.width = this.width
            this.renderFrame(false)
        }
        if (changedProperties.has('height')) {
            this.canvas.height = this.height
            this.renderFrame(false)
        }
    }

    render() {
        const { alt } = this.props
        return <canvas role="img" aria-label={alt}></canvas>
    }

    play = () => {
        if (this.animationFrame) cancelAnimationFrame(this.animationFrame)
        this.animationFrame = requestAnimationFrame(this.step)
        this.playing = true
    }

    pause = () => {
        this.playing = false
        if (this.animationFrame) cancelAnimationFrame(this.animationFrame)
    }

    restart = () => {
        this.currentFrame = 1
        if (this.playing) {
            this.play()
        } else {
            this.pause()
            this.renderFrame(false)
        }
    }

    step = () => {
        let previousTimestamp
        return (timestamp) => {
            if (!previousTimestamp) previousTimestamp = timestamp
            const delta = timestamp - previousTimestamp
            const delay = this.frames[this.currentFrame]?.delay
            if (this.playing && delay && delta > delay) {
                previousTimestamp = timestamp
                this.renderFrame()
            }
            this.animationFrame = requestAnimationFrame(this.step)
        }
    }

    renderFrame = (progress = true) => {
        if (!this.frames.length) return
        if (this.currentFrame === this.frames.length - 1) {
            this.currentFrame = 0
        }

        this.context.putImageData(this.frames[this.currentFrame].data, 0, 0)
        if (progress) {
            this.currentFrame = this.currentFrame + 1
        }
    }

    loadSource = async (url) => {
        const response = await fetch(url)
        const buffer = await response.arrayBuffer()
        const uInt8Array = new Uint8Array(buffer)
        const gifReader = new GifReader(uInt8Array)
        const gif = gifData(gifReader)
        const { width, height, frames } = gif
        this.width = width
        this.height = height
        this.frames = frames
        if (!this.alt) {
            this.alt = url
        }
        this.renderFrame(false)
    }
}

function gifData(gif) {
    const frames = Array.from(frameDetails(gif))
    return { width: gif.width, height: gif.height, frames }
}

function* frameDetails(gifReader) {
    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
    const context = canvas.getContext('2d')

    if (!context) return

    const frameCount = gifReader.numFrames()
    let previousFrame

    for (let i = 0; i < frameCount; i++) {
        const frameInfo = gifReader.frameInfo(i)
        const imageData = context.createImageData(gifReader.width, gifReader.height)
        if (i > 0 && frameInfo.disposal < 2) {
            imageData.data.set(new Uint8ClampedArray(previousFrame.data.data))
        }
        gifReader.decodeAndBlitFrameRGBA(i, imageData.data)
        previousFrame = {
            data: imageData,
            delay: gifReader.frameInfo(i).delay * 10,
        }
        yield previousFrame
    }
}
```

However, I'm getting all kinds of TypeScript errors. I also don't know how to style `:host` css property.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Hah. It's stupid how difficult this exercise is... I should have a demo by tonight. I always wanted a React GIF player component too.

Comment: Thank you @qiu, would love to see it :)

Comment: Hey, please correct me here but we can import the class and use its methods inside the custom react component instead of converting the whole class to react component?

Comment: @VaibhavRai yes, we can do that too. MobX works like that. We create an ES6 class to store state & then we can call it from React like we would in JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick link for people who don't want to read this wall of text: [repository link](https://github.com/diracs-delta/gif.tsx-demo)

This was a pretty fun project. I'm not guaranteeing that I support all use-cases, but here is a modern-day implementation that takes advantage of TypeScript. It also prefers the more modern and composable React Hook API over using class components.

The basic idea is that you have `useGifController` hook, which is linked to a canvas via a `ref`. This controller then allows you to handle loading and error states on your own, and then control the GIF rendered in a canvas as needed. So for example, we could write a `GifPlayer` component as follows:

### `GifPlayer.tsx`

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react'
import { useGifController } from '../hooks/useGifController'

export function GifPlayer(): JSX.Element | null {
  const canvasRef = useRef<HTMLCanvasElement>(null)
  const gifController = useGifController('/cradle.gif', canvasRef, true)

  if (gifController.loading) {
    return null
  }

  if (gifController.error) {
    return null
  }

  const { playing, play, pause, restart, renderNextFrame, renderPreviousFrame, width, height } = gifController

  return (
    <div>
      <canvas {...gifController.canvasProps} ref={canvasRef} />
      <div style={{ display: 'flex', gap: 16, justifyContent: 'space-around' }}>
        <button onClick={renderPreviousFrame}>Previous</button>
        {playing ? <button onClick={pause}>Pause</button> : <button onClick={play}>Play</button>}
        <button onClick={restart}>Restart</button>
        <button onClick={renderNextFrame}>Next</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>Width: {width}</p>
        <p>Height: {height}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Here, you can see the `gifController` expects a URL containing the GIF, and a `ref` to the canvas element. Then, once you handle the `loading` and `error` states, you have access to all of the controls `GifController` provides. `play`, `pause`, `renderNextFrame`, `renderPreviousFrame` all do exactly what you would expect.

So, what's inside of this `useGifController` hook? Well... it's a bit lengthy, but hopefully I've documented this well-enough so you can understand after studying it for a bit.

### `useGifController.ts`

```
import { GifReader } from 'omggif'
import {
  RefObject,
  DetailedHTMLProps,
  CanvasHTMLAttributes,
  useEffect,
  useState,
  MutableRefObject,
  useRef,
} from 'react'
import { extractFrames, Frame } from '../lib/extractFrames'

type HTMLCanvasElementProps = DetailedHTMLProps<CanvasHTMLAttributes<HTMLCanvasElement>, HTMLCanvasElement>

type GifControllerLoading = {
  canvasProps: HTMLCanvasElementProps
  loading: true
  error: false
}

type GifControllerError = {
  canvasProps: HTMLCanvasElementProps
  loading: false
  error: true
  errorMessage: string
}

type GifControllerResolved = {
  canvasProps: HTMLCanvasElementProps
  loading: false
  error: false
  frameIndex: MutableRefObject<number>
  playing: boolean
  play: () => void
  pause: () => void
  restart: () => void
  renderFrame: (frame: number) => void
  renderNextFrame: () => void
  renderPreviousFrame: () => void
  width: number
  height: number
}

type GifController = GifControllerLoading | GifControllerResolved | GifControllerError

export function useGifController(
  url: string,
  canvas: RefObject<HTMLCanvasElement | null>,
  autoplay = false,
): GifController {
  type LoadingState = {
    loading: true
    error: false
  }

  type ErrorState = {
    loading: false
    error: true
    errorMessage: string
  }

  type ResolvedState = {
    loading: false
    error: false
    gifReader: GifReader
    frames: Frame[]
  }

  type State = LoadingState | ResolvedState | ErrorState

  const ctx = canvas.current?.getContext('2d')

  // asynchronous state variables strongly typed as a union such that properties
  // are only defined when `loading === true`.
  const [state, setState] = useState<State>({ loading: true, error: false })
  const [shouldUpdate, setShouldUpdate] = useState(false)
  const [canvasAccessible, setCanvasAccessible] = useState(false)
  const frameIndex = useRef(-1)

  // state variable returned by hook
  const [playing, setPlaying] = useState(false)
  // ref that is used internally
  const _playing = useRef(false)

  // Load GIF on initial render and when url changes.
  useEffect(() => {
    async function loadGif() {
      const response = await fetch(url)
      const buffer = await response.arrayBuffer()
      const uInt8Array = new Uint8Array(buffer)

      // Type cast is necessary because GifReader expects Buffer, which extends
      // Uint8Array. Doesn't *seem* to cause any runtime errors, but I'm sure
      // there's some edge case I'm not covering here.
      const gifReader = new GifReader(uInt8Array as Buffer)
      const frames = extractFrames(gifReader)

      if (!frames) {
        setState({ loading: false, error: true, errorMessage: 'Could not extract frames from GIF.' })
      } else {
        setState({ loading: false, error: false, gifReader, frames })
      }

      // must trigger re-render to ensure access to canvas ref
      setShouldUpdate(true)
    }
    loadGif()
    // only run this effect on initial render and when URL changes.
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, [url])

  // update if shouldUpdate gets set to true
  useEffect(() => {
    if (shouldUpdate) {
      setShouldUpdate(false)
    } else if (canvas.current !== null) {
      setCanvasAccessible(true)
    }
  }, [canvas, shouldUpdate])

  // if canvasAccessible is set to true, render first frame and then autoplay if
  // specified in hook arguments
  useEffect(() => {
    if (canvasAccessible && frameIndex.current === -1) {
      renderNextFrame()
      autoplay && setPlaying(true)
    }
    // ignore renderNextFrame as it is referentially unstable
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, [canvasAccessible])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (playing) {
      _playing.current = true
      _iterateRenderLoop()
    } else {
      _playing.current = false
    }
    // ignore _iterateRenderLoop() as it is referentially unstable
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, [playing])

  if (state.loading === true || !canvas) return { canvasProps: { hidden: true }, loading: true, error: false }

  if (state.error === true)
    return { canvasProps: { hidden: true }, loading: false, error: true, errorMessage: state.errorMessage }

  const { width, height } = state.gifReader

  return {
    canvasProps: { width, height },
    loading: false,
    error: false,
    playing,
    play,
    pause,
    restart,
    frameIndex,
    renderFrame,
    renderNextFrame,
    renderPreviousFrame,
    width,
    height,
  }

  function play() {
    if (state.error || state.loading) return
    if (playing) return
    setPlaying(true)
  }

  function _iterateRenderLoop() {
    if (state.error || state.loading || !_playing.current) return

    const delay = state.frames[frameIndex.current].delay
    setTimeout(() => {
      renderNextFrame()
      _iterateRenderLoop()
    }, delay)
  }

  function pause() {
    setPlaying(false)
  }

  function restart() {
    frameIndex.current = 0
    setPlaying(true)
  }

  function renderFrame(frameIndex: number) {
    if (!ctx || state.loading === true || state.error === true) return
    if (frameIndex < 0 || frameIndex >= state.gifReader.numFrames()) return
    ctx.putImageData(state.frames[frameIndex].imageData, 0, 0)
  }

  function renderNextFrame() {
    if (!ctx || state.loading === true || state.error === true) return
    const nextFrame = frameIndex.current + 1 >= state.gifReader.numFrames() ? 0 : frameIndex.current + 1
    renderFrame(nextFrame)
    frameIndex.current = nextFrame
  }

  function renderPreviousFrame() {
    if (!ctx || state.loading === true || state.error === true) return
    const prevFrame = frameIndex.current - 1 < 0 ? state.gifReader.numFrames() - 1 : frameIndex.current - 1
    renderFrame(prevFrame)
    frameIndex.current = prevFrame
  }
}
```

This in turn depends on `extractFrames`, which extracts the frames as `ImageData` objects along with their respective delays.

### `extractFrames.ts`

```
import { GifReader } from 'omggif'

export type Frame = {
  /**
   * A full frame of a GIF represented as an ImageData object. This can be
   * rendered onto a canvas context simply by calling
   * `ctx.putImageData(frame.imageData, 0, 0)`.
   */
  imageData: ImageData
  /**
   * Delay in milliseconds.
   */
  delay: number
}

/**
 * Function that accepts a `GifReader` instance and returns an array of
 * `ImageData` objects that represent the frames of the gif.
 *
 * @param gifReader The `GifReader` instance.
 * @returns An array of `ImageData` objects representing each frame of the GIF.
 * Or `null` if something went wrong.
 */
export function extractFrames(gifReader: GifReader): Frame[] | null {
  const frames: Frame[] = []

  // the width and height of the complete gif
  const { width, height } = gifReader

  // This is the primary canvas that the tempCanvas below renders on top of. The
  // reason for this is that each frame stored internally inside the GIF is a
  // "diff" from the previous frame. To resolve frame 4, we must first resolve
  // frames 1, 2, 3, and then render frame 4 on top. This canvas accumulates the
  // previous frames.
  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
  canvas.width = width
  canvas.height = height
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
  if (!ctx) return null

  for (let frameIndex = 0; frameIndex < gifReader.numFrames(); frameIndex++) {
    // the width, height, x, and y of the "dirty" pixels that should be redrawn
    const { width: dirtyWidth, height: dirtyHeight, x: dirtyX, y: dirtyY, disposal, delay } = gifReader.frameInfo(0)

    // skip this frame if disposal >= 2; from GIF spec
    if (disposal >= 2) continue

    // create hidden temporary canvas that exists only to render the "diff"
    // between the previous frame and the current frame
    const tempCanvas = document.createElement('canvas')
    tempCanvas.width = width
    tempCanvas.height = height
    const tempCtx = tempCanvas.getContext('2d')
    if (!tempCtx) return null

    // extract GIF frame data to tempCanvas
    const newImageData = tempCtx.createImageData(width, height)
    gifReader.decodeAndBlitFrameRGBA(frameIndex, newImageData.data)
    tempCtx.putImageData(newImageData, 0, 0, dirtyX, dirtyY, dirtyWidth, dirtyHeight)

    // draw the tempCanvas on top. ctx.putImageData(tempCtx.getImageData(...))
    // is too primitive here, since the pixels would be *replaced* by incoming
    // RGBA values instead of layered.
    ctx.drawImage(tempCanvas, 0, 0)

    frames.push({
      delay: delay * 10,
      imageData: ctx.getImageData(0, 0, width, height),
    })
  }

  return frames
}
```

I do plan on making this an NPM package someday. I think it'd be pretty useful.

Comment: This is brilliant. Tysm. One tip: Make the Github repo work directly on Stackblitz or CodeSandbox. I like Stackblitz so I tried https://stackblitz.com/github/diracs-delta/gif.tsx-demo but it gave too many errors that I couldn't fix. PS: If you make a library, lmk. I would also love to have support for `initialPlay` which plays it 5 (or any other no.) times when it comes in viewport & then shows pause button to not play constantly as that was the reason I posted this question. Again, thank you :)

Comment: My bad, I didn't leave any instructions on how to start the dev server. You need to run `yarn vite` to get it up and running, and then navigate to `localhost:3000`.

Comment: I think `autoplayLoops = number | 'infinity'` would probably be a better parameter to `useGifController`, alongside a parameter to toggle whether autoplay begins when the user scrolls it into the viewport.

Comment: you have better ideas. additional idea: an example recipe to add play, pause button like video players, eg, https://vimejs.com/demo but play & pause button in the middle. that's all ideas i have & tysm again. do msg me if/when u release this library so i can swap this code out with it :)